# Configuring Neo4j on Rails to Deploy with Warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, warbler

How do you configure a Neo4j on Rails app to deploy with Warbler? As it stands, every time I deploy my app, the previous production instance of neo4j gets destroyed, because neo4j is embedded. I was hoping that there would be some kind of configuration for production, either through Warbler or through neo4j, so that once a neo4j instance is created on the server it is not replaced with the next deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could place the neo4j database somewhere persistent outside your volatile codebase and then open Neo4j against e.g. /var/database ? In case there are existing files, Neo4j will not replace them.